# Excel Formula Dependent on Currency in Cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet for expenses that I want to be able to apply a formula to the Subtotal column if the currency is JMD.  Else, I want to leave sum unchanged. Here is an row that I want to apply to.  I only will have one value in one of the columns.

[image]

I need the subtotal column to take the column in the row that has a value, if it is JMD, then I need to multiply the value times ".0089" for converting to USD.  If the value is USD, then I need to put the value as is in the subtotal column.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of format is JMD currency in compared to USD currency? Are they all numbers formatted with the currency on the front? Will JMD always been listed in Column K?

Comment: Any of the cells E through K can contain either JMD or USD, but only one in the row will have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding a column in which you choose USD or JMD ideally from a drop down (see data validation). If you add it to the left of the current column C, the formula could be as follows:

```
=sum(F9:M9)*IF(C9="USD",1,0.0089)
```

Simple, explicit and easy to maintain!

Comment: This worked perfect for this scenario...thanks.  Can you help me with the totals of each column?  Each column could have either JMD or USD and I want to add them to total USD.  So sum the column and perform a conversion from JMD to USD before adding cells.  Does this make sense to you?  At the bottom of each column, I have an expense total.

Comment: So you are looking at subtotals at the bottom of each column E through K (as pictured)? If that is the case, I would suggest taking a look at sumproduct(). I have answered a few questions using sumproduct. Check those out, see if you can come up with something and post back. I don't want to spoon feed all of the answers! :)

Comment: Thanks Jacob...I will look at these as I am not looking for spoon feeding ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may have other conditions that you might want to account for down the road, but the following formula addresses your question as is:

Enter the following in cell M9 and copy down as needed:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*USD*",E9:L9,0),0)<>0,TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(E9:L9,MATCH("*USD*",E9:L9,0)),"USD ",""),"0.00"),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*JMD*",E9:L9,0),0)=0,"",TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(E9:L9,MATCH("*JMD*",E9:L9,0)),"JMD ","")*0.0089,"0.00")))
```

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: I tried this and nothing appears but the formula in the text entry area above the actual cells.  Cell M9 is blank.

Comment: Per your example above, Cell M9 SHOULD be blank (or a dash).  When there are no values in Columns E:L for any given row, my formula is written to return a blank cell as this is often 'friendly' to other formulas that might reference the result that it returns (stock formulas don't know how to handle a dash without some adjustments).  Try copying it down to subsequent rows and let me know if you still have issues as it functions fine on my end.  Cheers!

Comment: There is a value in K9, so the value of M9 should be the value there multiplied by .0089

Comment: I believe this doesn't work because you are applying the USD and JMD as formatting rather text typed directly into the cell (e.g. type `1000`, format as `USD 1,000` compared to typing in `USD 1,000`).